# Run SQL query based on drop down value

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");
if(isset($_POST['type'])== "enquiry")
{
    query for enuiry;

}
else{
    query for enroll;
}

?>
<form action="dropd.php" method="POST">
<select name="type">
<option>Please select:</option>
<option value="enquiry">Student enquiry</option>
<option value="enroll">Student enrollment</option>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</select>
</form>
```

Hi.. I want to run two different SQL query based on drop down selection. I dont know how to do it. I am fresh to php. Guide me please.

Comment: Google is your friend...

Comment: even expert to php can not answer to your question ...

Comment: Open DB connection, build query, execute query? I don't see what the problem is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   if(isset($_POST['type']))
   {
       if($_POST['type'] == "enquiry")
       {
            Query
       }
       elseif($_POST['type'] == "enroll")
       {
            Query
       }
       else
       {
          echo "Please select enquiry or enrollment";
       }
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Please select an option";
   }

}

?>
<form action="dropd.php" method="POST">
<select name="type">
<option value="">Please select:</option>
<option value="enquiry">Student enquiry</option>
<option value="enroll">Student enrollment</option>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: In this answer there is error in HTML part and don't know how it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be this:

```
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == "enquiry")
  {
     query for enuiry;

  } else {
     query for enroll;
  }
}
?>
<form action="dropd.php" method="POST">
<select name="type">
  <option value=''>Please select:</option>
  <option value="enquiry">Student enquiry</option>
  <option value="enroll">Student enrollment</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```